# Why does Yukteshwar say that all religions are the same?

Tags: neo-vedanta

In the *Holy science*, neo-Hindu follower Yukteshwar says all religions are equal:

> The purpose of this book is to show as clearly as possible that there is an essential unity in all religions; that there is no difference in the truths inculcated by the various faiths; that there is but one method by which the world, both external and internal, has evolved; and that there is but one Goal admitted by all scriptures.

If that is the case, then how are there clear differences between the Abrahamic religions and Hinduism? For example, the [Old Testament says](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2031%3A1-18&version=NASB):

> Now therefore, kill every male among the little ones, and kill every woman who has known man intimately. But all the girls who have not known man intimately, spare for yourselves.

But this is clearly against Hinduism:

> Āpastamba (2.10, 11).—‘The Āryas forbid the killing of those who have laid down their arms, of those who beg for mercy with flying hair or joined palms, and of fugitives.’
>
> Baudhāyana (1.18.11).—‘He shall not fight those in fear, intoxicated, insane or out of their minds; nor those who have lost their armour; nor with women, infants, aged men and Brāhmaṇas.’

[Jesus in the Bible also says](https://biblia.com/bible/esv/john/9/1-5) that people suffer not due to their sins, but simply because of God's will:

> As he passed by, he saw a man blind from birth. And his disciples asked him, “Rabbi, who sinned, this man or his parents, that he was born blind?” Jesus answered, “It was not that this man sinned, or his parents, but that the works of God might be displayed in him.

This contradicts the Hindu teaching that people suffer due to their individual karma.

From this it is clear that Jesus was non-Vedic.

But why does Yukteshwar says all religions are the same when there are contradictions in all religions?

Comment: There are many versions of Jesus that contradict each other. It wouldn't be wise to rely on the Bible solely for the teachings of Jesus. Gnostic gospels which are not accounted in the Bible should all be accounted for.